# Getting actions in action bar to fill the whole bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using the support library for the action bar. I have a bunch of menu items that have `showAsAction` set to `ifRoom`. However, they only seem to occupy about half of the action bar . My action bar has no title so I was wondering if there's a way to get the actions to occupy more (all?) of the action bar. It looks as if there's some space reserved for the title.

I tried `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` but no luck. Also tried adding a custom view of size `0/0`, but that still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, here's the solution I ended up settling on: have all the items in the menu set to `ifRoom` and then, when inflating the menu, doing some calculations to force some of them to be `always` instead.

In the calculations, I took the width of the screen in dp, then subtracted estimated values for the icon, the title/subtitle section, and then for each of the action items in the menu. Final solution ended up working pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE)? You can also check android's style.xml and override width of title if any.

Comment: That is exactly the same as setDisplayShowTitleEnabled: `setDisplayOptions(showTitle ? DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE : 0, DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);` (source code taken from `ActionBarImplBase`)